# static_cast<> behaviour on class with implicit conversion operator that returns a const reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class (stripped down to contain only the relevant parts):

```
#include <string>

class Text
{
private:
    std::string _text;

public:
    Text(std::string&& text) :
        _text(std::move(text))
    {
    }

    operator const std::string&() const
    {
        return _text;
    }
};
```

My question is: if I want to obtain a `const std::string&`, can I do it like this without any penalty:

```
 Text text("fred");

 auto& s = static_cast<std::string>(text);
```

Or will this construct an intermediate `std::string` that I end up getting a reference to? Is there a standard approach to this kind of scenario? I am reasonably new to C++.

Comment: @Snps, yes that's right.

Comment: did you tried `static_cast<std::string&>(text)` ?

Comment: this is the kind of moment you want to use `explicit`

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot, static_cast<const std::string&> will do it, I am interested in how the compiler treats `auto& s = static_cast<std::string>` though.

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: @Christian Hackl, it compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @keith: No, it does not, unless I make a lot of tedious modifications. You cannot use `std::string` without `#include <string>`, and the semicolon at the end of the class definition is missing. It is furthermore unclear where you instantiate the `text` and `s` objects (e.g. are they local or static). You make everyone who tries to help you perform boring extra work.

Comment: @keith: P.S.: copy-and-paste-into-editor-and-run-compiler is the first thing many people here do with code posted in a question.

Comment: @Christian Hackl, OK I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: @keith: Thanks. Reverting my downvote because the class definition is now compilable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, when you're calling `static_cast<std::string>(text)`, you're calling the implicitly defined copy constructor and creating a temporary object.

However, if you would be calling

```
auto& s = static_cast<const std::string&>(text);
```

,then you would correctly be calling the explicit conversion operator `operator const Noisy&()`.

## Let's try it out

```
struct Noisy {
    Noisy() { std::cout << "Default construct" << std::endl; }
    Noisy(const Noisy&) { std::cout << "Copy construct" << std::endl; }
    Noisy(Noisy&&) { std::cout << "Move construct" << std::endl; }
    Noisy& operator=(const Noisy&) { std::cout << "C-assign" << std::endl; return *this; }
    Noisy& operator=(Noisy&&) { std::cout << "M-assign" << std::endl; return *this; }
    ~Noisy() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Text {
public:
    Text(Noisy&& text) : _text(std::move(text)) {}
    operator const Noisy&() const { return _text; }
private:
    Noisy _text;
};
```

#### Test 1

```
int main() {
    Text text(Noisy{});
    const auto& s = static_cast<Noisy>(text); // Needs 'const' to bind to temporary.
}
```

> Default construct
>   Move construct
>   Destructor
>   Copy construct
>   Destructor
>   Destructor

#### Test 2

```
int main() {
    Text text(Noisy{});
    auto& s = static_cast<const Noisy&>(text);
}
```

> Default construct
>      Move construct
>      Destructor
>      Destructor

**<sub>Note: Compiled using option `-fno-elide-constructors` to avoid copy elision optimizations.</sub>**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behavior here, when you `static_cast` to `std::string` and not `const std::string &`, is determined by this part of the C++11 standard:

[expr.static.cast] [5.2.9.4]:

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)`
>   if the declaration `T t(e)`; is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The effect of such an
>   explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary
>   variable as the result of the conversion. The expression `e` is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization
>   uses it as a glvalue.

If you `static_cast` to `const std::string &` then I would expect that no copy would be made. But if you `static_cast` to `std::string`, you must get a `std::string` value out -- it should always be the case that `decltype(static_cast<T>(e))` is the same as type `T`. The only way that a new `std::string` could be constructed is with the `std::string` copy ctor, and because your conversion operator is not marked `explicit`, it is a valid implicit conversion to get a `std::string` from `Text` that way.

> Or will this construct an intermediate std::string that I end up getting a reference to?

It will construct an intermediate `std::string` that you end up getting *by value*.

Comment: Thanks Chris Beck, my variable `s` is declared `auto&` so it will definitely be a reference to the intermediate string that `s` holds. If you can clear up that point for me, I think you have the answer.

Comment: @keith, sorry went afk, looks like Snps got you covered though :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not even legal C++ for exactly that reason. If you static_cast to something, you will get out *exactly that something and nothing else*.

Comment: It compiles, so it must be legal.

Comment: @keith, "It compiles, so it must be legal" is a notion that I would recommend you to disabuse yourself of with haste, in C++. It's quite common for beginners to write code that compiles and even seems to work, but is illegal, and gives "undefined behavior, no diagnostic required" or relies on compiler-specific extensions or implementation details. On SO almost all questions are in the context of the international C++ standard, not any compiler-specific behaviors. That is what the word "illegal" refers to in most questions and answers here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chris Beck, I will try to remember that. In this case it is legal though?

Answer (score 0):

At first, the compiler creates a temp variable in the middle of the cast operation:

```
int main()
{
    string temp = "foo";
    cout << &temp << endl;
    Text text(move(temp));
    auto s = static_cast<string>(text);
    cout << &s << endl;
    return 0;
}

$ main
0x7fffb9dd7530
0x7fffb9dd7540
```

As you can see the address of the variable has changed

Secondly, The compiler shadows all the `const, volatile` etc. modifiers when you use `auto`

```
void f (int i) {}

auto s = static_cast<const string&>(text);
f(s);
```

> error: cannot convert **'std::basic_string'** to 'int' for argument
>   '1' to 'void f(int)'

So if you need `const std::string&` you need to apply it to the `auto` variable:

```
const auto& s = static_cast<string>(text);
f(s);
```

> error: cannot convert **'const std::basic_string'** to 'int' for
>   argument '1' to 'void f(int)'

As you can see the `auto` keyword shadows the `const` identifier.